# How do I stop my python turtle from moving?

Tags: python, graphics, controls, conditional-statements, turtle-graphics

So I am making a game with python turtle where the player moves the turtle left and right by pressing the corresponding arrow keys. The turtle cannot move up or down in any way. Only left and right. But when my turtle reaches a certain xcor value I want the turtle to stop moving even if I am still pressing that arrow key. But still be able to move the opposite direction with the other arrow key.

```
def playerRight(): 
  player.goto(player.xcor() + 8,player.ycor())
  if player.xcor() >= 200:

def playerLeft():
  player.goto(player.xcor() - 8,player.ycor())
  if player.xcor() <= -200:

screen.onkey(playerRight,'Right')
screen.onkey(playerLeft,'Left')
screen.listen()
```

But I have no clue what to put in my conditionals. A reply is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try the `screen.onkeyrelease` function

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not familiar with that function. How and where do I use it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You use it like you do with `screen.onkey`. For example, if your method to stop the turtle was `playerStop`, you would want `screen.onkeyrelease(playerStop,'Right')` and `screen.onkeyrelease(playerStop,'Left')`

Comment: I don't think you understood my question Minion Jim. I want the turtle to stop once the player reaches a certain xcor value. Not when the player releases the arrow key. My game I am making is similar to space invaders. If you have played or seen that game the player is moving left and right and if they go to far to the left or right there will be an invisible wall blocking the player from going off screen.

Comment: Well, think about it logically. What *should the value of `player.xcor()` be* after the function call, when that `if` condition is met?

Comment: So Prune if someone asked you what a certain word means. Are you gonna tell them "You should have looked in the dictionary before asking."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try changing your code to only move the turtle if it won't go too far, like so.

```py
def playerRight(): 
  if player.xcor() <= 192:
    player.goto(player.xcor() + 8,player.ycor())
```

Now it only moves to the right if it doing so won't make it go to far. You then do the same thing for the `playerLeft()` function

You also have your inequalities the wrong way around (< where you need >)